# firebase custom auth workflow to do custom auth

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

I can't seem to be able to implement firebase custom auth. I'm new to programming and I cant find any reference to create custom auth from scratch. My application is android based social report.
the following are my use cases :

1. I need an admin to manage the data (CRUD the report)
2. Normal user to post reports

I did some research.

Based on what I've read, I need to create custom auth to differentiate normal users and admin.

I don't know the proper way to implement my auth server. I'm thinking of putting my users data (admin and normal user) on firebase. Is it viable? Do I need to create a separate database of users on my auth server to verify the auth? Can you please explain the workflow of firebase custom authentication?

Comment: Refer this link. I hope you got solution. https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/custom.html

Answer (score 0):

From the terse description you've given, it doesn't sound like your regular users need custom auth. They can just as easily use email+password or one of the supported social providers to authenticate. Given that you indicate being new to programming *and* the fact that getting authentication right is hard, I highly recommend not building your own authentication for these users.

Whether your administrators require custom authentication tokens is also debatable. From what you tell about their tasks, they are *application administrators*: users who fulfill a special role within the application. Those you can easily model in your Firebase security rules. As for regular users, if you can use a built-in identity provider for these administrator, it significantly reduces the chance of introducing a security hole.